# How to convert/migrate pyisical attached virtual machine to virtual disk or upload to esxi

Tags: migration, vmware

THis request made me dysphoric, we have one VM with physical disk attached, this vm can write to this physical drive directy, now we must upload this vm to our esxi server to save places(this is pc), but I could not neither upload nor convert to virtual disk, so cannot migrate anymore.
client vm: centos
host: windows server 2012
vmware workstation version: 12.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbVEC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways this can be performed.

Since you're on a version of Workstation higher than 8.0, you might be able to connect directly to the ESXi host (or vCenter Server) and upload the VM. Here's the process to accomplish it: http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-8C854257-8595-4877-B985-1DC801E98E88.html

If that doesn't work, you should try the vCenter Converter. It's a free "trial" through the following: https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html

Here's a good walkthrough on how to use the converter: http://thesolving.com/virtualization/how-to-convert-a-vmware-workstation-vm-into-an-esxi-one-with-vcenter-converter/

Comment: THanks Kyle, your suggestions was greate but when I was trying so Vmware told me physical disk attached VM cannot be migrate&uploaded, so what I have thinked all about this was use disk copy tool such as ghost, imagex or another tools i don't know currently, copy or ghost to file, then use CONVERTOR to convert this to another format that can be imported to VCENTER , but as I am not famlar with CENTOS, so do you know more details ? thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Kyle, we found another workaround to do this. that was create similar VM in target box, use database sync/import/export tools to sync all databases to target, then we can close source box, in our case, we use xtrabackup tool, thanks for your help.